# Discount for individual customization only in PrestaShop shopping cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

[Pedram poses a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157086/1240123) regarding discounts for product `customizations`.

**Example**

If you apply a specific price for 100 pieces, let's say 5% discount, and you add 50 t-shirts with ***print A*** and 50 t-shirts with ***print B***, you get a discount. But in reality only 50 pieces of one print production is sold. So there shouldn't been any discount (perhaps in my opinion).

*Let's take a crazy example*, say we have 100 different prints, then you would have to set up the printing production 100 times! And there for the discount for 100 pieces is not appropriate anymore.

**Question**

How can I make discounts (specific price) only apply to an indivual `customization` in the cart?

**Further thought**

My guess is that it should be changed somewhere in the core. Hopefully with a not to invasive class override. The setting `PS_QTY_DISCOUNT_ON_COMBINATION` tells if a discount should apply to the whole product or only to the combination. This setting is used in `SpecificPriceCore::getSpecificPrice()`, and doesn't seem to be the key in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible *combinations*, setting a specific price for *customizations* (not to be confused) is unfortunately is not yet supported in the Core.

It looks that this cannot be done by means of an override because you'd probably need to add a new parameter to `getSpecificPrice()`, among others.

Feel free to submit a pull request if you want this feature added to the Core (branch develop for 1.7), or [add a ticket to the forge](http://forge.prestashop.com/).